# how to represent and display 9 bit image using opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a 8-bit grayscale image and I apply a transformation (modified census transform) to it. After transformation I need to represent each pixel of the image with 9-bit. I store my 9-bit data in uint16 and when I want to display my image I used two different methods. I'm not sure which one is the right way to do it or if there are any better approaches to do it.

1- Take the most significant 8-bit from the 9-bit and represent image as 8-bit.

2- Divide each pixel value to 2 and represent image as 8-bit.

In both way there is a loss of information. Could anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Normalize them? 8bit,9bit whatever. normvalue=currentvalue/max. Display the normalized image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just normalize them?  `normalizedValue=currentValue/maximumValue`. Then just display the normalized image?

Answer (score 1):

The number of intensity levels which you can represent depends very much on your hardware. Even if you somehow manage to represent extra grey levels you wont be able to differentiate among them. The two methods which you proposed in your question are essentially the same.